# regex and scrapy in web crawling

Tags: regex, scrapy

I do a web crawling use scrapy. currently, it can extract the start url but not crawl later.

```
 start_urls = ['https://cloud.cubecontentgovernance.com/retention/document_types.aspx']

allowed_domains = ['cubecontentgovernance.com']
rules = (
     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("document_type_retention.aspx?dtid=1054456",)),
         callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)
```

And the link i want to extract in the develop tool is:`<a id="ctl00_body_ListView1_ctrl0_hyperNameLink" href="document_type_retention.aspx?dtid=1054456"> pricing </a>`

the corresponding url is `https://cloud.cubecontentgovernance.com/retention/document_type_retention.aspx?dtid=1054456`

so what the allow field should be? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

When I try to open the site of your start URL I get a login window.

Did you try to `print response.body` in the simple `parse` method for your start URL? I guess your Scrapy instance gets the same login window which does not have the URL you want to extract with the `LinkExtractor`.

Comment: no, the log in authentication works well, and the parse function extract what i need  in the start url page. but still thx for reply